# Running stored macros from an autocall library

Tags: macros, sas

I am running into errors when trying to execute a stored macro from an AUTOCALL library.

I have stored a macro within a folder using the following:

```
libname myMacr 'C:\My Macros';
options mstored sasmstore = myMacr;

%macro HelloWorld() / store;
  %put Hello, world!;
%mend;
```

When I look in the folder after running this, I see a catalog `sasmacr.sas7bcat` has been created, as expected.

Next, I've added `C:\My Macros` to my AUTOCALL library list.  By running

```
proc options option=config;
run;
```

to locate my config file.  Following the directions given in [Creating an autocall macro library on a PC](http://support.sas.com/kb/24/451.html), I added `C:\My Macros` to the AUTOCALL list.  Closing and reopening SAS, I can confirm my folder has been added to the AUTOCALL list using:

```
%put %sysfunc(pathname(sasautos));
```

Indeed, `C:\My Macros` appears in the list.  Furthermore, I can confirm that SAS sees the compiled macro.  When I issue:

```
proc catalog;
  contents catalog=sasautos.sasmacr;
quit;
```

I get the output

```
                              Contents of Catalog SASAUTOS.SASMACR

 #    Name          Type     Level            Create Date          Modified Date    Description

 1    HELLOWORLD    MACRO       14    03/21/2017 18:44:28    03/21/2017 18:44:28
```

However, when I issue `%HelloWorld();`, I get an error:

```
1    %HelloWorld();
     -
     180
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro HELLOWORLD not resolved.

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is there some option I'm overlooking which must be turned on?  What do I need to do in order to run stored macros from my `C:\My Macros` folder?

Comment: Note that an an autocall library (which holds .sas code) and a library of compiled macros are different things.  Sounds like you may be confusing the two.

Comment: This is somewhat confusing as SAS makes ambiguous statements like "Generally, an autocall library is a directory containing individual files, each of which contains one macro definition. In SAS 6.11 and later, an autocall library can also be a SAS catalog."  However, you are correct.  SAS also describes "The stored compiled macro facility [which] compiles and saves compiled macros in a permanent catalog in a library that you specify."  Thank you for alerting me to how describes them separately.

Comment: Autocall: https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/69726/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1o5fkxq0gqdpcn1xs3ksdks69tf.htm

Stored Compiled Macro Facility: https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/69726/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0sjezyl65z1cpn1b6mqfo8115h2.htm

Answer (score 0):

Put the line

```
-initstmt "options mstored sasmstore=sasautos;"
```

in the config file.  This will issue the command within quotes when SAS initializes.

[MSTORED](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/69726/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1she0gfz2wh4sn1c8fwaeajjc4r.htm)

[SASMSTORE=](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/69726/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p156rt5c7ikat4n1o2n1dnb4jlza.htm)